# Event Study in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have a time series as so:

```
pd.Series(np.random.rand(20), index=pd.date_range("1990-01-01",periods=20))
```

Which gives,

```
1990-01-01    0.018363
1990-01-02    0.288625
1990-01-03    0.460708
1990-01-04    0.663063
1990-01-05    0.434250
1990-01-06    0.504893
1990-01-07    0.587743
1990-01-08    0.412223
1990-01-09    0.604656
1990-01-10    0.960338
1990-01-11    0.606765
1990-01-12    0.110480
1990-01-13    0.671683
1990-01-14    0.178488
1990-01-15    0.458074
1990-01-16    0.219303
1990-01-17    0.172665
1990-01-18    0.429534
1990-01-19    0.505891
1990-01-20    0.242567
Freq: D, dtype: float64
```

Suppose the event date is on 1990-01-05 and 1990-01-15. I want to subset the data down to a window of length (-2,+2) around the event like this:

```
1990-01-03    0.460708
1990-01-04    0.663063
1990-01-05    0.434250
1990-01-06    0.504893
1990-01-07    0.587743
1990-01-13    0.671683
1990-01-14    0.178488
1990-01-15    0.458074
1990-01-16    0.219303
1990-01-17    0.172665
Freq: D, dtype: float64
```

How should I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) all `Series` created by `list comprehension` with [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.loc.html):

```
date1 = pd.to_datetime('1990-01-05')
date2 = pd.to_datetime('1990-01-15')
window = 2

dates = [date1, date2]

s1 = pd.concat([s.loc[date - pd.Timedelta(window, unit='d'): 
                      date + pd.Timedelta(window, unit='d')] for date in dates])
print (s1)
1990-01-03    0.284356
1990-01-04    0.997019
1990-01-05    0.293225
1990-01-06    0.451379
1990-01-07    0.743209
1990-01-13    0.254926
1990-01-14    0.339728
1990-01-15    0.793124
1990-01-16    0.121002
1990-01-17    0.930924
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but the two dates given are two event dates. Using your method can handle one at a time, are you suggeting me to do a for loop for the two event dates case?

Comment: I think yes, `iloc` can be problematic in starts `1990-01-01` and end dates `1990-01-17`.

Comment: I would use BDay: delta.loc[date1 - BDay(window): date1 + BDay(window)] - This because some windows end or start during the weekend

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:

```
In [23]: df['A']
Out[23]: 
2013-01-01    0.469112
2013-01-02    1.212112
2013-01-03   -0.861849
2013-01-04    0.721555
2013-01-05   -0.424972
2013-01-06   -0.673690
Freq: D, Name: A, dtype: float64

In [25]: df['20130102':'20130104']
Out[25]: 
                   A         B         C         D
2013-01-02  1.212112 -0.173215  0.119209 -1.044236
2013-01-03 -0.861849 -2.104569 -0.494929  1.071804
2013-01-04  0.721555 -0.706771 -1.039575  0.271860

[3 rows x 4 columns]
```

from the cookbook: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.13.1/10min.html?highlight=select%20where ("selection" item)

Answer (score 1):

I would build a boolean mask to choose the interesting values:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series(np.random.rand(20), index=pd.date_range("1990-01-01",periods=20))
events = [pd.to_datetime('1990-01-05'), pd.to_datetime('1990-01-15')]
max_delta = pd.Timedelta(2, unit='d')

mask = np.zeros_like(s, dtype=bool)
for event in events:
    mask |= np.abs(s.index - event) <= max_delta
s_events = s[mask]

print(s_events)
```

Output:

```
1990-01-03    0.877271
1990-01-04    0.770214
1990-01-05    0.427380
1990-01-06    0.971676
1990-01-07    0.533582
1990-01-13    0.060556
1990-01-14    0.932072
1990-01-15    0.501966
1990-01-16    0.081177
1990-01-17    0.167775
dtype: float64
```